# Items not able to add in reactjs shopping cart

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a shopping cart in react and redux. But the, problem which I'm facing is that I'm not able to add the item in the cart.

Following is my code for it.

action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_NAVBAR = "GET_NAVBAR";
export const GET_PRODUCTS = "GET_PRODUCTS";
export const GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL = "GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL";
export const ADD_CART = "ADD_CART";
export const REMOVE_CART = "REMOVE_CART"

export const BASE_API_URL = "http://localhost:3030";


export const getNavbar = () => {
    return axios.get(BASE_API_URL + '/topCategory').then(res => {
        return {
            type: GET_NAVBAR,
            payload: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        };
    });
};

export const getProducts = (id) => {
    return axios.get(BASE_API_URL + '/category/'+id).then(res => {
        return {
            type: GET_PRODUCTS,
            payload: res.data.express.catalogEntryView
        };
    });
};

export const getProductDetail = (id) => {
    return axios.get(BASE_API_URL + '/product/'+id).then(res => {
        return {
            type: GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL,
            payload: res.data.express.catalogEntryView
        };
    });
};

export function addToCart(item) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD',
        item: item
    };
  }

  export function removeFromCart(item) {
    return {
        type: 'REMOVE',
        item: item
    };
  }
```

In the reducer folder I have used two js files -

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import fashion from "./fashionReducer";
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    fashion: fashion
});
```

fashionReducer.js

```
import {GET_NAVBAR, GET_PRODUCTS} from "../actions";
import {GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL} from "../actions/index";
import {ADD_CART} from "../actions/index";
import {REMOVE_CART}from "../actions/index";

const INITIAL_STATE = {navbar: [], products: [], productDetail:[], cartDetail:[]};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_NAVBAR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navbar: action.payload
            };
        case GET_PRODUCTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload
            };
        case GET_PRODUCT_DETAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                productDetail: action.payload
            };

        case ADD_CART:
        return{
            ...state,
            cartDetail: action.payload
        };

        case REMOVE_CART:

        const firstMatchIndex = state.indexOf(action.payload)
        return state.filter((item, index) => index!==firstMatchIndex) 

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In the below code I have a product List and a buttom to add to the cart.

PDP.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Route, Link, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getProductDetail} from "../actions";
import { addToCart } from '../actions/index';


class PDP extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let currentId = this.props.match.params.id;
        let previousId = prevProps.match.params.id;
        if (currentId !== previousId) {
            this.props.getDetails(currentId);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let {id} = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.getDetails(id);
    }

    render() {
        const {productDetail} = this.props;

        const picUrl = "https://149.129.128.3:8443";
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        {productDetail &&
                        productDetail.map(pdpList => {
                            return (
                                <div key={pdpList.uniqueID} className="col-md-4">
                                    <h2 key={pdpList.uniqueID}/>

                                    <img src={picUrl + pdpList.thumbnail}/>
                                    <p>
                                        Price : {pdpList.price[0].value}{" "}
                                        {pdpList.price[0].currency}
                                    </p>
                                    <button  onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(item)}>Add to Cart</button>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        productDetail: state.fashion.productDetail,
        cartDetail: state.fashion.cartDetail
    }
};

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getDetails: getProductDetail
    }, 
    {
        addToCart: item => dispatch(addToCart(item))
    },dispatch);

};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(PDP)
```

;

cart.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeFromCart } from '../actions/index';

class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    /**
     * this.props.cart is populated through the redux store and mapStateToProps
     * this.props.removeFromCart is added through mapDispatchToProps
     */
    const cartList = this.props.cart.map(( item, index) =>{
      return <div key={index}> 
        <p style={{ color: "#767676"}}>{item.name} - {item.price} $ </p>
        <button className="button" 
                onClick={ () => this.props.removeFromCart(item)} > 
          Remove 
        </button>
      </div>;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cart</h1>
        <div  className="cart">
          {cartList}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        cart: state.cartDetail
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        removeFromCart: pdpList => dispatch(removeFromCart(pdpList))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cart);
```

The only error I'm getting is

[image]

Can someone please help me to troubleshoot this issue. I dont know whereI got wrong. I would be grateful if someone could provide me an insight. Thanks

Comment: You're passing `item` to `this.props.addToCart`, but you never define a variable called `item`.

Comment: So, what should I do now. Can you guide me a little @JoeClay

Comment: I think instead of item pass pdpList if pdpList is your one item of your product list. Its work hope so. Please declare proper variable name.

Comment: Yeah, what @Dhiren said is what I was about to say :) Pass the correct variable name into `this.props.addToCart` - judging by the code, you meant to pass `pdpList`.

Comment: I have changed and now it is showing error in my Cart.js file. I have uploaded my updated code. Please help

Comment: @Dhiren I have changed the code. Not it's showing map of undefined error in Cart.js. I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here `<button  onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(item)}>Add to Cart</button>` because `item` is `undefined`, You need to replace `item` with `pdpList` variable.

```
<button  onClick={() => this.props.addToCart(pdpList)}>Add to Cart</button>
```

updating as per Question update
now the problem lies in this line

```
const cartList = this.props.cart.map(( item, index) =>{ // this.props.cart is `undefined`
```

Your cart prop is `undefined`

You need to define `cart` in `INITIAL_STATE` of `fashionReducer.js`

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {navbar: [], products: [], productDetail:[], cartDetail:[], cart: []};
```

OR you can use cartDetail(already defined) in `mapStateToProps` like so

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        cart: state.fashion.cartDetail // changed
    };
}
```

Comment: I have changed everything as said by you. But still it is showing Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Your cart state lies in fashion reducer. so use `state.fashion.cart` instead of `state.cart`. I thought u have mapped the state correctly. anyway

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think the main issue is with your **mapStateToProps**

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        cart: state.fashion.cartDetail // instead of state.cart 
    };
}
```

there is no any property in your state named cart that is why.

Comment: After changing, it's still showing  Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @SajjadTabreez Hi i came to know that you are using combineReducers so you have to access state via **state.fashion** so i have updated my answer.

Comment: @SajjadTabreez : Your welcome :) please check answer as true. :p